# How much weight can 4x12x16.9' header support

Tags: wood

16' garage door header also supports 14ea 2x10x20' rafters and 600lbs of metal roofing so will 2ea 2x12x16'9" w plywood in-between carry this weight load here in sunny Hawaii ( rafters depending on how dry they are can total 840 to 1120 lbs

Answer (score 1):

Probably not... Almost all the homes we do now (here in sunny Hawaii) require a glu lam beam for a garage door header. The widths and heights vary  dependng on other factors of your house design.

I would at least use a 3.5" x 12" glu lam and not a 4x12. Even 2- 2x12's with plywood between has not been standard here for over 30 years.

To really get an accurate answer to your specific situation you will need to contact an architect or a structural engineer.

Comment: But what if I use construction adhesive between layers of the 2x12,

Comment: The answer is the same- typically, that is not done here. You need to get an engineer to sign off on that.